# Can getActivity return null when using a viewpager?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm getting a lint warning that getActivity may return null, so i was wondering when getActivity might return null which would be a problem because im using getActivity as a context.

I read in other posts to use onAttach which is deprecated, so what is the best way to get a context or to be sure getActivity() won't return null?

I'm also using a viewPager with fragments so the fragments are attached to an Activity right, so normally it wouldn't return null?

```
  public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private int numOfTabs;

    SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.numOfTabs = numOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                Log.i(TAG, "Fragment Pos: "+ position);
                return new Tab1();
            case 1:
                Log.i(TAG, "Fragment Pos: "+ position);
                return new Tab2();
            case 2:
                Log.i(TAG, "Fragment Pos: "+ position);
                return new Tab3();
            case 3:
                Log.i(TAG, "Fragment Pos: "+ position);
                return new Tab4();
            case 4:
                Log.i(TAG, "Fragment Pos: "+ position);
                return new Tab5();
            case 5:
                Log.i(TAG, "Fragment Pos: "+ position);
                return new Tab6();
                default:
                    return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Get total pages
        return numOfTabs;
    }
}
```

**setupViewPager() method:**

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter
    mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. U can always use the context from the view itself `viewPager.getContext()`
2. It's ok to use the `getActivity()` as long as U know for sure that in that point the activity will not be null e.g in `onActivityCreated`.

and if you want to get rid from the lint warning, just put null check on the `getActivity` var.